# How to retrieve values of dynamically created controls in code behind?

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, dynamically-generated, html-input

I intend to use Javascript to dynamically create a group of html elements (input boxes, select list, radio button, etc.) each time the user clicks "Add More" button.

I have found the Javascript that does that here:

- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript.html
- http://forums.asp.net/p/1611284/4118564.aspx

So how do I get the values of these dynamically created HTML elements from code-behind? Is there a JQuery way which is better?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd may be able to do it with a callback/async postback to your ASP.NET page to update the control tree as you update. Not sure how the ViewState is updated/affected by this.

Otherwise, because your messing with the ViewState, so you'll need to revert to accessing them by the Request.Form object.